# Sum of all .png sizes

Tags: r, directory

Is there any possibility to sum all .png sizes in folder ? I know there is a function `file.size()` but it does not exactly match my expectations. I want to have function which input is a folder and in output I have sum of all .png files within it. Alternatively is there any function as `file.size()` but which refers to folders (`folder.size()`) ?

Comment: "png size"? Do you mean the image sizes in disk space or in actual "image size" (eg. pixel X pixel)?

Comment: in working directory. So in the folder getwd()

Comment: I meant whether it was the size allocated to your harddisk or whether you were interested in the "image size" (eg the size of the image when you open the file to view it). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path <- "..."
file_paths <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = TRUE)
sum(file.size(file_paths))
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking for **disk** space you could just iterate over the files in the folder

```
dir <- getwd() #change
files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
sizes <- file.size(files)
sum(sizes)
[1] 107764
```

Note the above number is the output on my pc.

Comment: Great and simple solution!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a little function to do this:

```
png_size <- function(path, unit=c("mb", "kb", "gb", "b")){
  unit <- match.arg(unit)
  files <- list.files(path = normalizePath(path), pattern="png$", full.names = TRUE)
  sz <- file.size(files)
  exponent <- switch(unit, 
                     "mb" = 2, 
                     "kb" = 1, 
                     "gb" = 3, 
                     "b" = 0)
  sz <- sum(sz)/1000^exponent
  paste0(round(sz, 3), " ", unit)
}
png_size("~/Downloads")
# [1] "4.132 mb"
```

The above would let you see the sum of sizes in megabytes (`mb`), kilobytes (`kb`), gigabytes (`gb`) or bytes (`b`).